# SQL How can I get 0 as output (HAVING COUNT())

Tags: mysql, having

I am having a problem with my sql query. I am trying to get a list of customer IDs for orders with no (0) orders before the one looked at and for orders with one (1) order before the one looked at.
The following query gives me the expected results for the third line (count_compl_ord_before_d_1) but no results for the second line (count_compl_ord_before_d_0):

```
SELECT created_at AS d, customer_id AS b,
(SELECT customer_id FROM orders WHERE customer_id = b AND created_at < d AND status = 'complete' HAVING COUNT(created_at) = 0 ) AS count_compl_ord_before_d_0,
(SELECT customer_id FROM orders WHERE customer_id = b AND created_at < d AND status = 'complete' HAVING COUNT(created_at) = 1 ) AS count_compl_ord_before_d_1
FROM orders
WHERE status = 'complete'
AND created_at >= '2017-06-08'
```

However, when I run the following, I get all different amounts from 0 up to xxx for count_compl_ord_before_d:

```
SELECT created_at AS d, customer_id AS b,
  (SELECT COUNT(created_at) FROM orders
   WHERE customer_id = b AND created_at < d
     AND status = 'complete') AS count_compl_ord_before_d
FROM orders
WHERE status = 'complete'
AND created_at >= '2017-06-08'
```

Is it a problem with `HAVING COUNT(created_at) = 0`?

I don't know a lot about SQL, but I'm trying to learn more, so I'd appreciate explanations.

Thanks in advance! Cheers

Comment: The `customer_id` expression (in the SELECT list of the correlated subquery) will evaluate to NULL when there are no rows. It's not a problem with the `HAVING COUNT()`... sure, the aggregate there causes all of the matched rows to be collapsed into a single row... but that's not the issue... the issue is that when zero rows get collapsed into a single row... there's no row to get a value of `customer_id` from.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Why do I get 0s as output in the second query then?

Comment: In the second query, the correlated second query is returning a `COUNT` aggregate. When there are no rows, `COUNT(created_at)` will return a value of zero. In the first query, the correlated subqueries are returning `customer_id`. And when there are no rows, `customer_id` will be NULL.